# Why can't this equation be solved for k?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This function for vertical position, where $g$ is gravity, $m$ is mass, $y$ is vertical position and $k$ is air drag constant,

[image]

, is obtained by solving the differential equation  for linear drag:

[image]

And then we integrate again and apply $y(0) = 0$ to obtain the equation above. I have been told that the first equation shown cannot be solved for $k$, but I want to know why is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be solved by our usual algebraic weapons because there is $k$ in the exponential as well as in the coefficient.  Some equations like this can be solved if you permit the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but that function is not in our usual bag of tricks.  You can solve it numerically to whatever precision you like.

Comment: +1, because I believe this is a good answer that didn't deserve the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is known, the equation can be solved, at least numerically. The analytic solution probably does not exist.